# Confirm right model

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Have a Khan problem I've been working under the "Related Rates" category.

GIVEN:

A 2 meter tall boy "h" is rollerskating away from a 5 meter 
lantern at constant dx/dt = 2 meters per second.

How fast is the tip of his shadow "s" moving away from the 
lantern (ds/dt in meters per second) when the boy is 7 meters 
from it?

[image: Illustration]

/GIVEN

My model is "s", the solution model offered is s'.

My model:

5/(s + x) = 2/s

5s/(s + x) = 2

5s = 2(s + x)

5s = 2s + 2x

3s = 2x

s = 2x/3

d/dt(s) = d/dt(2x/3)

d/dt(s) = 2/3*d/dt(x)

ds/dt = 2/3*dx/dt

dx/dt = 2

ds/dt = 2/3*2

ds/dt = [4/3]

Solution Model:

Let

x be the distance from the base of the lantern to the boy;

s be the distance from the base of the lantern to the tip 
of the shadow.

Then dx/dt = 2m/sec and ds/dt is the speed at which the 
tip of the boy's shadow is moving away from the lantern.

Based on similar triangles we know that:

s/(lantern height) = (s − x)/(boy's height)

That is, s/5 = (s − x)/2

We solve this equation for s in terms of x.

2s = 5s - 5x

5x = 3s

s = 5x/3

Take the derivative with respect to time of both sides.

ds/dt = 5/3*dx/dt

Since we are given thatdx/dt = 2 msec,

we conclude that

ds/dt = 5/3*(2m/sec) = [10/3]m/sec ???

I maintain my model is more correct based on the constraints of the given information. I don't see how the actual shadow "s" can be set to the overall length as depicted with s'.

Any thouhgts?

Answer (score 1):

In your model $s$ seems to be the length of the shadow, i.e. the distance from the tip of the shadow to the boy. You have shown the length is increasing at $\frac43 m/s$.

But the boy is moving at $2 m/s$ away from the lantern and the question asks "How fast is the tip of his shadow moving away from the lantern?" So the answer is $2+\frac43=\frac{10}{3} m/s$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

1. You have $\frac{ds}{dt}=4/3$
2. They have $\frac{ds'}{dt}=10/3$
3. Also notice that $\frac{ds}{dt} + \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{ds'}{dt}$

In other words 4/3 + 2 = 10/3.  You just forgot that the whole shadow is moving at 2 m/s and needed to add 2.